# How to match WireMock query param with any string value

Tags: java, wiremock

I would like to do something like this:

```
    mockServer.givenThat(WireMock.get(URL_PATH)
        .withQueryParam("param", WireMock.any())
        .willReturn(WireMock.ok(SOMETHING)));
```

So basically, I don't care what will be passed in `param` parameter, but I want to make sure that it was passed.

The problem is that there is no `any()` method in WireMock. And I could not find anything similar.

Digging a little bit in the WireMock classes I found there is a `AnythingPattern` that extends `StringValuePattern` and always matches. Basically, exactly what I need, which I could use just by instantiating it with a constructor, but it really does not feel right (depending on a concrete implementation).

Another workaround would be to use `matching(".*")`, which would do the trick, but strictly speaking it is not the same.

Do you know any more elegant way to do this, please?

Strangely enough I could not find any discussion about it in the web. So, I wonder, maybe what I ask doesn't even make sense? :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I think the `absent()` function](https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#absence) would be useful in this case. Pairing it with `not()` should get you there.

```
mockServer.givenThat(WireMock.get(URL_PATH)
    .withQueryParam("param", WireMock.not(WireMock.absent()))
    .willReturn(WireMock.ok(SOMETHING)));
```